# How to custom deserialize null values into C# Nullable<T> using the BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, nullable, binaryformatter

I have an old legacy type which basically does the same thing as the C# nullable introduced in C# 2.0. And I have old persisted data containing that legacy type serialized with the binary formatter. I would like to remove the legacy type completely (and replace it with the C# nullable) and handle all required type conversion in the deserialization of the persisted data.

I have almost managed to do this using serialization binders and surrogates. However. I can not figure out how to get my legacy null values to deserialize into proper null values of the C# nullable type, instead of getting a null value I get an uninitialized object of the underlying (non-nullable) type.

The below sample will print out the following, but I want null instead of 0 on the last line:

```
Before serialization: 17
Before serialization: <null>
After serialization: 17
After serialization: 0
```

The type I want to replace in the following sample is NullableInt which acts as a wrapper around the non-nullable Int class (the latter is used for creating strongly typed integers, but that is not important for my question).

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace ConsoleApplication7 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Non-nullable typed integer. We use these for creating strongly typed
    /// integers to make it harder to mix up integers having different
    /// purpose (like mixing up Int<PatientId> with Int<ExaminationId>).
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    internal struct Int<T> {

        public int Inner;

        public Int(int inner) {
            this.Inner = inner;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used as generic type argument to the typed integer
    /// </summary>
    internal struct PatientId {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Nullable typed integer. This is the legacy type I want to 
    /// replace with the C# nullable, i.e. Int<T>?
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    internal struct NullableInt<T> {

        private object inner;
        public static NullableInt<T> Null = new NullableInt<T>();

        public Int<T> Value { get { return new Int<T>((int)inner); } }
        public bool IsNull { get { return (inner == null); } }

        public NullableInt(Int<T> value) {
            this.inner = value.Inner;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SerializationBinder used during deserialization. It will map the legacy
    /// type to the C# nullable type.
    /// </summary>
    internal class Binder : SerializationBinder {
        public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName) {
            if (typeName == typeof(NullableInt<PatientId>).FullName) {
                return typeof(Int<PatientId>?);
            } else {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SerializationSurrogate converting the legacy binary format
    /// of NullableInt<T> to C# nullable
    /// </summary>
    internal class Surrogate<T> : ISerializationSurrogate {
        public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector) {
            // Get the object serialized by NullableInt<T>
            object inner = info.GetValue("inner", typeof(object));

            // Always return Int<T>?
            Int<T>? nullable = (inner == null) ? (Int<T>?)null : new Int<T>((int)inner);
            return nullable;
        }
        public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Main program testing serialization and deserialization
    /// </summary>
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Create data to serialize
            var data = new NullableInt<PatientId>[2] {                
                new NullableInt<PatientId>(new Int<PatientId>(17)),
                NullableInt<PatientId>.Null
            };
            data.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(
                "Before serialization: " + (x.IsNull ? "<null>" : x.Value.Inner.ToString())));

            // Serialize into memory stream
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, data);

            // Set up binder for deserialization
            formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Binder = new Binder();

            // Setup surrogate for deserialization
            var surrogateSelector = new SurrogateSelector();
            surrogateSelector.AddSurrogate(
                typeof(Int<PatientId>), 
                new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All), 
                new Surrogate<PatientId>());
            surrogateSelector.AddSurrogate(
                typeof(Int<PatientId>?), 
                new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All), 
                new Surrogate<PatientId>());
            formatter.SurrogateSelector = surrogateSelector;

            // Deserialize
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);            
            var deserialized = (Int<PatientId>?[])formatter.Deserialize(ms);
            deserialized.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(
                "After serialization: " + (x.HasValue ? x.Value.Inner.ToString() : "<null>")));
        }
    }
}
```

Notice at the end that I do get an array of nullables back, the last one just is not null (but instead an uninitialized Int with inner value 0).

Two additional observations:

1. If I remove the 1st surrogate, i.e. the first call to AddSurrogate, the ISerializationSurrogate does not get called at all
2. If I remove the 2nd surrogate, the ISerializationSurrogate does get called but with the SerializationInfo argument always set to null.

Does anyone know what to return from the serialization surrogate to make the binary formatter return a null value instead of an uninitialized value? Or is there another way of doing what I want to do? I have also played around with implementing the IObjectReference interface, but without any luck.